# What would be Linq for Following

Tags: c#, linq

Following is the case for which I intend to write my LINQ query, but it does not work:

`List <Clients>` has client info and in this list there is `List<JobCards>`, which represents the list of job cards of that person. The job card list has one attribute named `Status`. I need to return all the active job cards in all Clients List.

Can it be done in LINQ?

Other code may be as follows:

```
BindingList<JobCard> activeJobs = new List<JobCards>();
foreach(var client in allClientList)
{
    foreach(var jobCard in client.JobCards)
    {
        if (jobCard.Status == "Active") 
        {
            activeJobs.Add(jobCard);
        }
    }
}
```

I am in the learning phase of LINQ. I am certain there is some error in what I've implemented, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is my LINQ query:

```
activeJobCards = new BindingList<JobCard>(
    mainForm.allData.Where(
        index => index.JobCards.Where(
            card => card.Status == "active"
        ).ToList().Count > 0
    ).ToList()
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

```
allClientList.SelectMany(c => c.JobCards).Where(jc => jc.Status == "Active");
```

`SelectMany()` will give you an `IEnumerable<JobCard>` and from there you select the Active job cards.

Answer (score 2):

```
allClientList.SelectMany(c => c.JobCards.Where(jc => jc.Status == "Active"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BindingList<JobCard> activeJobs = new List<JobCards>();
activeJobs.AddRange(allClientList.SelectMany( x=> x.JobCards)
                                 .Where( y => y.Status == "Active"));
```